# Jenkins maven build is Finished succcessfully on console still it shows task in progress

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins

I tried to deploy my maven project on svn using Jenkins to Tomcat server. The Jenkins build shows Finished success still the progressbar shows task in progress. The project is also not deployed on server.

The log looks like this :

```
11:33:30 [INFO] Processing war project
11:33:30 [INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\10748\.jenkins\workspace\TomcatDeployment\src\main\webapp]

11:33:34 [INFO] Webapp assembled in [3781 msecs]
11:33:34 [INFO] Building war: C:\Users\10748\.jenkins\workspace\TomcatDeployment\target\brandtrackeradmin2.war

11:33:37 [INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
11:33:37 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:33:37 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
11:33:37 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:33:37 [INFO] Total time: 26.800 s
11:33:37 [INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-05T11:33:37+05:30

11:33:37 [INFO] Final Memory: 26M/146M
11:33:37 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

11:33:39 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: For the loading bar, does reloading the page make that go away?  As for the deployment issue, maybe this is a separate problem.

Comment: Yes the progress bar vanished on page refresh...but the project is not deployed. Can you tell me the probable reason for this?

Comment: Well at least we've decoupled two potential problems.  I'm not so expert with Jenkins that I can just guess what the problem is, but it sounds like now you need to focus on your deployment setup.  Go through the steps of deployment from that machine manually, and see if you can do it.  If even that gives you errors along the way, then obviously it would happen for Jenkins too.

Comment: The problem is there is no error log. But in tomcat I cannot see my project deployed so that I can access it

Comment: Yeah I know the feeling.  I just posted a Jenkins question myself a few days ago...it's not always the best in giving feedback, but +1 to you.

Comment: Its ok...Thanks Tim

Comment: The deployment setup, how did you setup? As a build step? Used any plugin?

Comment: Deploy to a container is not configured for building Can you check it once?

Comment: I have installed Deploy to container plugin...But still it does'nt work